# Como fazer o programa rodar a partir de qualquer ponto da programação

Tags: python, pyautogui

Tenho um programa usando pyautogui que preenche 20 formularios web de forma sequencial, mudando pagina por pagina automaticamente e coloquei um temporizador pra cada pagina de 5 segundos. Geralmente as paginas carregam em 2 segundos o que me da uma folga, porém as vezes ele demora 20 segundos e o programa continua operando encavalando as funçoes.
Gostaria de ter uma linha que deixasse eu começar de qq uma das 20 páginas.

```
import pyautogui
#Pagina 1#
pyautogui.press('tab') # na pagina 1 ele seleciona a caixa de mensagem
pyautogui.write('pagina 1') # escreve "pagina 1" na caixa de mensagem
pyautogui.press('tab', presses=2) # pula até o botao "proxima pagina"
pyautogui.press('enter') # seleciona o botao
pyautogui.sleep(5) # espera 5 segundos ate continuar o proximo comando
#Pagina 2#
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write('pagina 2')
pyautogui.press('tab', presses=2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.sleep(5)
#Pagina 3#
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write('pagina 3')
pyautogui.press('tab', presses=2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.sleep(5)
```

Se as paginas fluirem com 2 segundos cada o programa finaliza as 20 paginas normalmente. Se uma delas demora pra carregar, o programa continua sem esperar. Preciso algo q eu possa parar o programa e mandar recomeçar da pagina X q encavalou... Ou algo que aguarde a pagina carregar e só assim continue, mas nao quero a opção de deixar todos em 20 segundos de espera por pagina. Obrigado a todos!

Comment: O sistema é web? Se sim, pense em usar o selenium, que permite aguardar a página ser carregada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então acredito que para automatizar funções no seu navegador a biblioteca recomendada seria Selenium, onde você consegue buscar informações através das classes do HTML da pagina. fica aqui a documentação do [Seleniun](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) para você entender melhor a aplicação e sua funcionalidades.

Porem se você quiser continuar usando o pyautogui recomendo você usar a função da biblioteca `pyautogui.locateOnScreen(caminho para foto)`, o retorno dessa função é as coordenadas de onde foi encontrado o print na tela que você estava no momento, assim você gera um laço de repetição ate o momento em que ela localiza na tela e faz o comando assim não importando o tempo que demorar a resposta.

fica aqui um exemplo de uso

```
import pyautogui
a = None

while a is None:
      a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'local do arquivo do print.png')

print(a)
```

mas ainda assim a biblioteca selenium é a melhor para esse tipo de automação, pois foi feita pensado nisso vou deixar um exemplo que existe na documentação da biblioteca

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente o modo com pyautogui.... inclui em cada inicio de comando de pagina e ele ficou muito otimizado... agora se carregar em 1 segundo ou em 10, ele só inicia após carregado e o melhor, ele não lê o print da pagina atual como sendo a próxima, ele realmente espera a próxima iniciar! Perfeito!!!!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha ajudado, uso muito esse padrão para poder rodar em aplicativos desktops em computadores diferentes também, assim não importando o tempo de resposta, mas fica a dica ai para próximos projetos o selenium pode ser extremamente util é mais otimizado.

Comment: Seria possível colocar essas 3 linhas de comando dentro de uma palavra?
Ex: 
`CARREGAMENTO = a = None
                                     while a is None:
                                     a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\>teste.png')`

Pq quando vou testar fora do site, ele não roda o programa e tenho que ir nas 20 paginas e colocar # em cada linha de comando para q ele não rode e consiga mostrar se o programa ta rodando bem... Se colocasse numa palavra, eu localizaria mais facil essa palavra e colocaria a # antes destas palavras

Comment: não entendi muito bem, mas para declarar variáveis em uma linha geralmente fazemos assim:
`variavel1, variavel2 = None, pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\>teste.png') `